# Telegram бот для чата, не работает меню бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Недавно начал интересоваться ботами. Решил написать бота для своего чата, но застрял на одном моменте.
Значит, когда новый участник добавляется в чат, бот сразу же бросает его в мут, присылает сообщение с правилами чата и кнопкой в духе "Нажмите, если согласны с правилами". Мут работает, сообщение с кнопкой отображается, но при нажатии не снимает мут.
Вот, собственно, код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot("")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Working")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"], func=lambda call: True)
def newmemb(message):
    bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, can_send_messages=False)
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Yes", callback_data="1")
    markup.row(btn)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Human?", reply_markup=markup)

 def callback_query(call):
    if call.data == "1":
        bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id, can_send_messages=True)
    else: pass

bot.polling()
```

Буду крайне благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import telebot
import json
import config
from telebot import types
 
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.lab_token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"], func=lambda call: True)
def new_member(message):
    bot.restrict_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id,
                             can_send_messages=False)
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Yes", callback_data="HumanScaner")
    markup.row(btn)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Human?", reply_markup=markup, reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
 
 
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_access(call):
    if call.data == "HumanScaner":
        CallBackDataJson = json.dumps(call.message.json)
        DataMessage = json.loads(CallBackDataJson)
        UserID = DataMessage['reply_to_message']['from']['id']
        if UserID == call.from_user.id:
            bot.restrict_chat_member(call.message.chat.id, call.from_user.id, can_send_messages=True)
            bot.delete_message(message_id=call.message.message_id, chat_id=call.message.chat.id)
 
 
bot.polling()
```

Этот код исправил проблему. Берите кому надо. Надеюсь, вам помогу.